Is there a way to make multiple calls in MongoDB all at once?
I'm a developer using MongoDB.
A server based on node.js is using mongoose.
It increases the score of the person you want, and I'm going to give him 5 points if he's a man and 10 points if he's a woman.
let person = await Person.findOne({_id:'66cb30f2f3aaaeb2676f0b81'}); // First call
let score = person.gender == 'female'? 10 : 5;
await Person.findOneAndUpdate({_id:'66cb30f2f3aaaeb2676f0b81'}, {'$inc' : {'score':score}}) // Second call

It works as you wish with the code above.
But, it's very uncomfortable to have MongoDB work twice, and I think there's a better alternative.
If MongoDB is on an external server, wasteful traffic twice.
The heart of my question is this.
Can multiple commands be grouped together and called at once?
I look forward to hearing from you.

What do you mean by multiple calls? Do you want to add points for multiple users? or multiple add points operations for a single user?

I've added content, so I'd appreciate it if you could read it again!


It's very uncomfortable to have MongoDB work twice, and I think there's a better alternative. If MongoDB is on an external server, wasteful traffic twice.

Because you are following bad practice, You don't need to offload the gender check, you can do it in the query itself.
await Person.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: '66cb30f2f3aaaeb2676f0b81' },
  [
    {
      $set: {
        points: {
          $cond: {
            if: { $eq: ["$gender", "male"] }, 
            then: 5,
            else: 10
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $inc: { score: "$points" }
    }
  ]
);

